# Executing ErrorFilter from inside action method catch block

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-filters

I am using a global ErrorHandler filter to log unhandled exceptions, but I would also like to be able to use this same handler to log handled exceptions from within a catch block.

I would like to access the global filters and execute the ErrorHandler as configured, but I'm having some difficulty doing this.  I tried the following, but Resharper is telling me that the filter can't ever be my ErrorLogFilter.

```
foreach (var filter in GlobalFilters.Filters)
{
    if (filter is ErrorLogFilter) // Static analysis tells me this can never be an ErrorLogFilter
    {
        // want to execute the filter
    }
}
```

ErrorLogFilter is added to the global filters like this:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ErrorLogFilter(provider));
```

ErrorLogFilter (as part of Elfar, similar to Elmah, but for MVC) is defined as:

```
public class ErrorLogFilter : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GlobalFilters.Filters` is a [GlobalFilterCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.globalfiltercollection%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) which contains [Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filter%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)'s which are wrappers around the added `IMvcFilter`s.

Try this instead:

```
foreach (var filter in GlobalFilters.Filters)
{
    if (filter.Instance is ErrorLogFilter)
    {
        // want to execute the filter
    }
}
```

So Reshaper is correct signaled that there is no `ErrorLogFilter` in `GlobalFilters.Filters`.